# JQuery Lightbox - Trouble closing lighbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have a JQuery lightbox I created which just displays a div in the center of the browser inside a lightbox.
I want it to be removed when the user clicks the transparent background around the lightbox.
However it is being removed when the div is being clicked also.

http://michaeloneill.ie/cs230/lightbox/lighbox.html

The JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    //click on the button
    $('.viewCart').click(function() {

        //markup for the lightbox
        var lightbox =  '<div id="lightbox">'+
    '<div id="lightboxContent">'+
        '<h3>Your Cart</h3>'+
    '</div>'+
        '</div>';

        //append the lightobx
        $('body').append(lightbox);                     
     });

     //remove the lightbox
     $('#lightbox').live('click', function() { //use live because lightbox can be added and removed dynamically
         $('#lightbox').remove();
     });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here by applying **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** since your `#lightbox` has been added dynamically to the DOM:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('body').on('click', '#lightbox', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

So basically, event delegation will help you to attach click event to this newly created `#lightbox` element in this case.

---

Edit: You can do like below:

```
//remove the lightbox
$(document).on('click', '#lightboxContent,.viewCart', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    $('#lightbox').remove();
});
```

Updated Fiddle: **[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/xGmqH/2/)** , **[Full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/xGmqH/2/embedded/result/)**

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but unfortunately it hasn't solved the problem. Your suggested code is now on the link...